# What is the exact data type of a nested table's index?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, nested-table

This will probably never actually matter, but I am curious. A nested table's indices are of course some form of integer, but that could be represented as a `NUMBER`, or an `INTEGER`, or a `PLS_INTEGER`, or a `BINARY_INTEGER`, etc.

Internally, what type (if any) are the indices, and what type is returned by methods like `FIRST` and `NEXT`?

In particular I'm curious about Oracle 11g, but it would also be interesting to know about differences in other versions, if it has changed.

Comment: Are you asking about nested table columns in SQL, or nested table collections in PL/SQL?

Comment: If they differ here, then both.